# Share relative layout width

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I try to create a layout (day view calendar) that texviews (tasks) are listed verticaly (by time scheduled). TextView height is according task duration classically as always. The problem is that I cannot manage to to share the horizontal space when two or more tasks have the same schedule time. That's because I use relative layout and I cannot use weights so in that situation the one textview is above the other. I cannot use LinearLayout because tasks may have gaps between them. Is there anyway to handle it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android1:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android1:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android1:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android1:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android1:id="@+id/tv_00"
                    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android1:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android1:height="@dimen/crm_calendar_time_row_height"
                    android1:text="00 πμ"
                    android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android1:textColor="@color/crm_calendar_time_row_color" />

                <TextView
                    android1:id="@+id/tv_01"
                    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android1:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android1:height="@dimen/crm_calendar_time_row_height"
                    android1:text="01 πμ"
                    android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android1:textColor="@color/crm_calendar_time_row_color" />

                <TextView
                    android1:id="@+id/tv_02"
                    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android1:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android1:height="@dimen/crm_calendar_time_row_height"
                    android1:text="02 πμ"
                    android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android1:textColor="@color/crm_calendar_time_row_color" />

                <TextView
                    android1:id="@+id/tv_03"
                    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android1:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android1:height="@dimen/crm_calendar_time_row_height"
                    android1:text="03 πμ"
                    android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android1:textColor="@color/crm_calendar_time_row_color" />

                <TextView
                    android1:id="@+id/tv_04"
                    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android1:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android1:height="@dimen/crm_calendar_time_row_height"
                    android1:text="04 πμ"
                    android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android1:textColor="@color/crm_calendar_time_row_color" />

                <TextView
                    android1:id="@+id/tv_05"
                    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android1:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android1:height="@dimen/crm_calendar_time_row_height"
                    android1:text="05 πμ"
                    android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android1:textColor="@color/crm_calendar_time_row_color" />

                <TextView
                    android1:id="@+id/tv_06"
                    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android1:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android1:height="@dimen/crm_calendar_time_row_height"
                    android1:text="06 πμ"
                    android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android1:textColor="@color/crm_calendar_time_row_color" />

                <TextView
                    android1:id="@+id/tv_07"
                    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android1:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android1:height="@dimen/crm_calendar_time_row_height"
                    android1:text="07 πμ"
                    android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android1:textColor="@color/crm_calendar_time_row_color" />

                <TextView
                    android1:id="@+id/tv_08"
                    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android1:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android1:height="@dimen/crm_calendar_time_row_height"
                    android1:text="08 πμ"
                    android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android1:textColor="@color/crm_calendar_time_row_color" />

                <TextView
                    android1:id="@+id/tv_09"
                    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android1:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android1:height="@dimen/crm_calendar_time_row_height"
                    android1:text="09 πμ"
                    android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android1:textColor="@color/crm_calendar_time_row_color" />

                <TextView
                    android1:id="@+id/tv_10"
                    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android1:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android1:height="@dimen/crm_calendar_time_row_height"
                    android1:text="10 πμ"
                    android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android1:textColor="@color/crm_calendar_time_row_color" />

                <TextView
                    android1:id="@+id/tv_11"
                    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android1:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android1:height="@dimen/crm_calendar_time_row_height"
                    android1:text="11 πμ"
                    android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android1:textColor="@color/crm_calendar_time_row_color" />

                <TextView
                    android1:id="@+id/tv_12"
                    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android1:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android1:height="@dimen/crm_calendar_time_row_height"
                    android1:text="12 πμ"
                    android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android1:textColor="@color/crm_calendar_time_row_color" />

                <TextView
                    android1:id="@+id/tv_13"
                    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android1:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android1:height="@dimen/crm_calendar_time_row_height"
                    android1:text="01 μμ"
                    android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android1:textColor="@color/crm_calendar_time_row_color" />

                <TextView
                    android1:id="@+id/tv_14"
                    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android1:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android1:height="@dimen/crm_calendar_time_row_height"
                    android1:text="02 μμ"
                    android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android1:textColor="@color/crm_calendar_time_row_color" />

                <TextView
                    android1:id="@+id/tv_15"
                    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android1:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android1:height="@dimen/crm_calendar_time_row_height"
                    android1:text="03 μμ"
                    android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android1:textColor="@color/crm_calendar_time_row_color" />

                <TextView
                    android1:id="@+id/tv_16"
                    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android1:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android1:height="@dimen/crm_calendar_time_row_height"
                    android1:text="04 μμ"
                    android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android1:textColor="@color/crm_calendar_time_row_color" />

                <TextView
                    android1:id="@+id/tv_17"
                    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android1:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android1:height="@dimen/crm_calendar_time_row_height"
                    android1:text="05 μμ"
                    android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android1:textColor="@color/crm_calendar_time_row_color" />

                <TextView
                    android1:id="@+id/tv_18"
                    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android1:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android1:height="@dimen/crm_calendar_time_row_height"
                    android1:text="06 μμ"
                    android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android1:textColor="@color/crm_calendar_time_row_color" />

                <TextView
                    android1:id="@+id/tv_19"
                    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android1:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android1:height="@dimen/crm_calendar_time_row_height"
                    android1:text="07 μμ"
                    android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android1:textColor="@color/crm_calendar_time_row_color" />

                <TextView
                    android1:id="@+id/tv_20"
                    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android1:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android1:height="@dimen/crm_calendar_time_row_height"
                    android1:text="08 μμ"
                    android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android1:textColor="@color/crm_calendar_time_row_color" />

                <TextView
                    android1:id="@+id/tv_21"
                    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android1:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android1:height="@dimen/crm_calendar_time_row_height"
                    android1:text="09 μμ"
                    android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android1:textColor="@color/crm_calendar_time_row_color" />

                <TextView
                    android1:id="@+id/tv_22"
                    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android1:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android1:height="@dimen/crm_calendar_time_row_height"
                    android1:text="10 μμ"
                    android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android1:textColor="@color/crm_calendar_time_row_color" />

                <TextView
                    android1:id="@+id/tv_23"
                    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android1:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android1:height="@dimen/crm_calendar_time_row_height"
                    android1:text="11 μμ"
                    android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android1:textColor="@color/crm_calendar_time_row_color" />

                <TextView
                    android1:id="@+id/tv_24"
                    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android1:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android1:height="@dimen/crm_calendar_time_row_height"
                    android1:text="12 μμ"
                    android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android1:textColor="@color/crm_calendar_time_row_color" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android1:id="@+id/rl_schedule"
                android1:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android1:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android1:orientation="vertical" >

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

<resources>

    <dimen name="crm_calendar_time_row_height">40dp</dimen>
    <color name="crm_calendar_time_row_color">#BBBBBB</color>

</resources>
```

This is my layout. I want to dynamically create tasks inside RelativeLayout but as I mention I cannot share horizontaly it's space when the tasks has the same schedule time.

Comment: appreciate if you put your layout here

Comment: You are right. I just did.